# Why am I not getting the output from the program. Whenever I run my code it stop after taking the input?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

Here is my code I am expecting the output but I am not getting .It stop after taking the input
I am expecting the output if i give name Harsh

> Your name is Harsh

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstring>
 using namespace std;
 
 int main() {
     cout << "Enter your name" << endl;
     char *s;
     cin >> s;
     cout << "Your name  is  " << s;
     return 0;
 }
```

I have also tried with `cin.getline(s,100);`but still it is not working.
So I request to you to solve the problem and give me solution.

Comment: Instead of using `char* s` use `std::string s`.

Answer (score 5):

Your code has **undefined behavior** because you are not allocating any memory for `s` to point at. `s` is an *uninitialized* pointer.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Enter your name" << endl;
    char s[100];
    cin >> s; // or: cin.getline(s,100);
    cout << "Your name is " << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you should use `std::string` instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Enter your name" << endl;
    string s;
    cin >> s; // or: getline(cin,s);
    cout << "Your name is " << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`s` in your code is unallocated.

Since it is C++ we're talking about, you probably don't want to use pointers and memory allocation, and use `std::string` instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main ()
{
  cout << "Enter your name" << endl;
  string s;  // Instead of dealing with char* allocation and memory issues.
  cin >> s;
  cout << "Your name  is  " << s;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: To use `std::string`, you need to use `<string>` instead of `<cstring>`

Comment: You're right, I copied the pasta from the OP

Answer (score -3):

you have done it correctly but the problem with output is because of the memory allocation.
You have to allocate memory and try to avoid the concept of a pointer in that. Instead
Use string s;
or
char s[50];

Comment: "*you have done it correctly*" - that is a misleading statement, because the code is clearly using `s` incorrectly.